# Stability of zero of a system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given a system
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=ax-y-x^5\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=ay-z-y^5\\
\frac{dz}{dt}=az-x-z^5\\
\end{cases}
$$
We want to study the stability of the zero solution.

We can linearize the system and get a matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -1 & 0\\
0 & a & -1\\
-1 & 0 & a\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues are $a-1$, $a+\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, $a+\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

If $a>-\frac12$, there is an eigenvalue with positive real part, meaning instability.

If $a<-\frac12$, all eigenvalues have negative real part, meaning asymptotic stability.

If $a=-\frac12$, linearization no longer works. I try to find a Lyapunov function. I tested $V=x^2+y^2+z^2$, but this fails to work.

> Question: How to study the stability of zero when $a=-\frac12$?

Comment: So what is the question? How to study stability when $a=-1/2$?

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes, edited.

Comment: @Saunders Why don't solve the system of (linearized) equations for that case? The closed-form solution exists.

Comment: @NN2 The solution is very complicated. And will the (in)stability of the linearized system tell us anything about the original one?

Comment: What makes you think $V=x^2+y^2+z^2$ doesn't work? After all, you get $\dot V = -(x+y+z)^2 - 2x^6 - 2y^6 - 2z^6$, which is negative definite.

Comment: @Hans Oops... I am making a serious computation mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that when eigenvalues with real part are equal to $0$, the system is still Lyapunov stable (there are several types of stability). But I took this course longtime ago and almost forget all. This solution should be easier than the one I propose below.

Now we find the closed-form solution of the linearized system for the case $a =-\frac{1}{2}$.

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{1}{2}x-y\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{1}{2}y-z\\
\frac{dz}{dt}=-\frac{1}{2}z-x\\
\end{cases}
\Longleftrightarrow  
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}x\right)e^{\frac{t}{2}}=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}y\\
\left(\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}y\right)e^{\frac{t}{2}}=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}z\\
\left(\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}z\right)e^{\frac{t}{2}}=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}x\\
\end{cases}
\Longleftrightarrow  
\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{t}{2}}x  \right)=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}y\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{t}{2}}y  \right)=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}z\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{t}{2}}z  \right)=-e^{\frac{t}{2}}x\\
\end{cases}\\ \tag{1}
$$
For the sake of simplicity, let's denote
$$(X(t),Y(t),Z(t)) = \left(e^{\frac{t}{2}}x,  e^{\frac{t}{2}}y,e^{\frac{t}{2}}z\right) $$
Then
$$(1)\Longleftrightarrow  
\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{dt}=-Y\\
\frac{dY}{dt}=-Z\\
\frac{dZ}{dt}=-X
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$
We have
$$(2) \Longrightarrow  X'''(t) =-X(t) \Longleftrightarrow  X(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{\frac{t}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_3e^{\frac{t}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)$$
We deduce easily $Y(t)$,$Z(t)$  and also the solution $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=c_1e^{-\frac{t}{2}}+c_2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_3\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
y(t)=c_4e^{-\frac{t}{2}}+c_5\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_6\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
z(t)=c_7e^{-\frac{t}{2}}+c_8\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_9\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
\end{cases} \tag{3}$$
With $(c_i)_{i=1,...,9}$ can be determined from initial condition.

It's my memory is still good, $(3)$ is stable as the solution converges to a stable solution $(x^{*}(t),y^{*}(t),z^{*}(t))$ for $t \to +\infty$
$$\begin{cases}
x^{*}(t)=c_2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_3\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
y^{*}(t)=c_5\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_6\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
z^{*}(t)=c_8\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)+c_9\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right)\\
\end{cases} $$
Then the initial system of equations is Lyapunov stable for $a = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I forgot to make the substitution $(x,y,z)\to(X,Y,Z)$... However, I think the zero of $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{dX}{dt}\\ \frac{dY}{dt}\\ \frac{dZ}{dt}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 &0\\0 & 0 & -1\\-1 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X\\ Y\\ Z\end{pmatrix}$$ is unstable, as $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 &0\\0 & 0 & -1\\-1 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalue with positive real part.

Comment: We use $(X,Y,Z)$ just for solving $(x,y,z)$. Even if $(X,Y,Z)$ is unstable (as you can see in the closed form solution of $X(t)$, there is the term $e^{0.5 t}$), $(x,y,z)$ is stable thanks= to the multiplicator factor $x(t) = \color{red}{e^{-0.5 t}} X(t)$

Comment: I see. Does the stability of the linearized system implies the stability of the original system?

Comment: @Saunders yes, as for the cases $a>-1/2$ and $a<-1/2$ that you proved in your question

Comment: This answer is not correct. In the case $a=-1/2$, when there are eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, you cannot say anything about the stability of the original nonlinear system through linearization alone (as was already stated in the question). It's true that the linearized system is neutrally stable, but the higher-order terms (i.e., $-x^5$, $-y^5$ and $-z^5$) in the original system may (or may not) ruin this.